# Append Existing UL to Existing Preceding LI

Tags: jquery, append, siblings

I'm attempting to move an existing `ul` into an existing `li` that is immediately preceding the `ul`.

```
<ul class="sub-menu" aria-labelledby="desktop-submenu">
  <li class="has-children current-page-ancestor current-page-parent">
    <a href="/improve-clinical-care/clear/" class="current_page_item">Clear</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
    <li class="level-three">
      <a href="/improve-clinical-care/clear/clears-story/" class="current_page_item">Clear's Story</a>
    </li>
    <li class="level-three current-menu-item page-item-34 current_page_item">
      <a href="/improve-clinical-care/clear/sign-up-for-clear/" class="current_page_item">Sign-Up for Clear<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li class="has-children critical-care">
    <a href="/improve-clinical-care/critical-care/" class="current_page_item">Critical Care</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
    <li class="level-three">
      <a href="/improve-clinical-care/critical-care/pain-agitation-delirium/" class="current_page_item">Pain Agitation &amp; Delirium</a>
    </li>
    <li class="level-three">
      <a href="/improve-clinical-care/critical-care/glycemic-control/" class="current_page_item">Glycemic Control</a>
    </li>
    <li class="level-three">
      <a href="/improve-clinical-care/critical-care/critical-care-working-group/" class="current_page_item">Critical Care Working Group</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is to move the `<ul class="sub-sub-menu">` items into the preceding `<li class="has-children">`, since we obviously can't have a `ul` as a child of another `ul`.

Is this even possible with jQuery? I've come so close with the `append()` method, but because there are so many occurrences of `has-children`, I end up with one of the `has-children` LIs with ALL the `sub-sub-menu`'s appended to it.

Any help on this would be so greatly appreciated. Thanks gang!

Comment: Is it possible to amend the HTML directly? That would be a much better solution, as doing this through JS would likely result in a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Comment: Also note that the HTML you currently have is invalid (as `ul` cannot be a child of another `ul`), so that will make any attempts to traverse the DOM more difficult.

Comment: Hey Rory. While I would love to be able to do that, the menu is dynamically created in WordPress and only displays second-level menu items, so I've had to make my third-level items into second-level ones and manipulate the HTML. I've asked another question as to whether you can output a third level of menu items with a certain WordPress function, but after searching around for hours already, it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: I also know that I can't have ul  as the child of another ul, which is why I'm asking the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own question - woo hoo!

```
$(".sub-sub-menu").each(function() {
    $(this).prev(".has-children").append(this);
});
```

Apparently I was getting really close a number of times, but was just missing `prev` instead of `siblings` or `closest`.